# SSRS Parameter show 1 and 0

Tags: reporting-services

Using SQL Server 2016 & SSRS. I may be missing something simple here, but I have a field (called `Errors`) in a report that has an Integer value of either 0 or 1.

I've added a parameter to my SSRS report called `Errors` and added 3 options:

```
1 = show error
0 = no error
1 or 0 = both
```

The `Both` option is not working - it doesn't return any records. I must be missing something. In Available Values I have a Label called 'Both'.  On the value I enter the expression:

```
= 1 OR 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like it's working perfectly.  Options are not code, and "1 or 0" != 0

Comment: "1 or 0" seems strange, I'd recommend changing it to "-1" or "2"

Comment: But the error field is an INT and can only ever be 0 or 1.  I don't understand -1 or 2?  How do I show records with both in SSRS?

Comment: I think you need to change the parameter to multiple-choice with just 1 and 0 as options, then lookup filtering on a multiple-choice parameter.. sorry been a while since I used ssrs but that should get you started

Comment: Are you using the parameter to filter the data already queried or are you using the parameter in the query?

Comment: I'm using a parameter to filter the data already queried

Answer (score 1):

The parameter doesn't work the way you want it to.

The `1 or 0` value is probably being evaluated as a text value.

My suggestion is to use -1 for *both* if it can't be in the data and change your parameter to an integer.

If you are using the parameter in a query, you add an OR to check for your both selection (-1).

```
WHERE (ERROR_FIELD = @ERRORS OR @ERRORS = -1)
```

This will check to see if the field matches the parameter or if the parameter = -1.

If you are using the FILTER on the dataset or table,

```
=IIF(Fields!ERROR_FIELD.Value = Parameters!ERRORS.Value OR Parameters!ERRORS.Value = -1, 1 , 0)
```

And set the Type to Integer and the value to 1.

Comment: Thanks for this, however, as I said in the original post the Error field is already an Integer.

Comment: Your field is an integer but your parameter can't be an integer that equals `1 or 0` - it's one or the other. The expression `=1 or 0` would return a value of TRUE or 1. Since you don't get any records with when using BOTH, it may be a text field that's returning "TRUE" which doesn't equal 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I got this working using an IN within the WHERE:

WHERE ERROR_FIELD IN (@Error)